# ¿Porqué no me funciona la pseudo clase :checked?

Tags: html, css

Soy principiante en desarrollo de páginas Web. Estoy intentado realizar un menú *"hamburguesa"* responsive desplegable utilizando un `<input type="checkbox />` con `id:"check"`. Lo que pasa es que al poner la resolución ya en pantallas en cierto porcentaje la "hamburguesa" no reacciona. Ya intenté de muchas formas y no me funciona.

Esto es lo que hice antes de ver una pregunta con el mismo problema:

```css
#check:checked ~ .menu{
    right: 0;
  }
```

```html
<header>
    <h2 class="logo">Corpotarive</h2>
    <input type=" checkbox" id="check">
    <label for="check" class="mostrar-menu">
      &#8801
    </label>
    <nav class="menu">
      <a href="#">Inicio</a>
      <a href="#">Sobre Nosotros</a>
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
      <label for="check" class="esconder-menu">
        &#215
      </label>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Luego de ver la posible solución en una situación similar puse lo siguiente:

```css
#check:checked + .navegacion .menu{
    right: 0;
  }
```

```html
<header>
    <h2 class="logo">Corpotarive</h2>
    <label for="check" class="mostrar-menu">
      &#8801
    </label>
    <input type=" checkbox" id="check">
    <nav class="menu">
      <a href="#">Inicio</a>
      <a href="#">Sobre Nosotros</a>
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
      <label for="check" class="esconder-menu">
        &#215
      </label>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Comment: Si gustas te puedo ayudar a resolver este problema pero utilizando `Javascript`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que `~` se usa para acceder al hermano inmediato, es decir, el siguiente elemento en el mismo nivel. [Referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator).

En el primer código, el selector `#check:checked ~ .menu` es correcto, pero no el HTML, porque el siguiente elemento es `<label>` y no el menú. Solo hay que poner la etiqueta antes del *checkbox* y debajo el menú.

Nunca he usado el `+` [selector de hermanos adyacentes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator), pero supongo que funciona de forma similar al anterior.

Combinando ambos códigos y, agregando un poco de CSS adicional, este fragmento de código funciona como esperas con `~`

```css
.mostrar-menu {
    /* Mostrar "hamburguesa" más grande y con diferente cursor */
    font-size: 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.menu {
    /* Evitar barra de desplazamiento en documento */
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: -100%;
}
#check {
    /* El checkbox debe estar oculto */
    display: none;
}
#check:checked ~ .menu {
    display: block;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h2 class="logo">Corpotarive</h2>
    <label for="check" class="mostrar-menu" title="Menú">
      &#8801
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <nav class="menu">
      <a href="#">Inicio</a>
      <a href="#">Sobre Nosotros</a>
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
      <label for="check" class="esconder-menu">
        &#215
      </label>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Comment: Gracias, muy acertado, gracias por la explicación y por la solución, me funcionó!